# Many 'cD' flag in haproxy log and many non-zero Send-Q connections. How to debug it?

Tags: tcp, server, haproxy

I use haproxy as tcp balancer for my servers. There are a few hundred non-zero Send-Q connections between haproxy and clients. And there are many 'cD' flag in haproxy log. Now many server responses reach clients very slowly(more than 10 seconds). Is it caused by clients not receiving data? Or haproxy server does not work properly? Or haproxy server reaches bandwidth limit? What can I do to find the reason?

```
#455 non-zero Send-Q connection
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-218:~$ netstat -atn|awk '{if($3>0) print $0}'|wc -l
455

#Top five Send-Q connections
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-218:~$ netstat -atn|awk '{if($3>0) print $0}'|sort -k3nr|head -n 5
tcp        0  27292 172.31.19.218:12135      :47685    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0  22080 172.31.19.218:12135      :11817       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0  21886 172.31.19.218:12135      :12755     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0  21584 172.31.19.218:12135      :8753      ESTABLISHED

#many 'cD' flags in haproxy log    
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-218:/var/log$ awk '{print $12}' haproxy.log | sort | uniq -c
      3 
   7525 --
   **4687 cD**
    526 CD
      1 /run/haproxy.pid
      3 SD

#some 'cD' flag logs
[27/Sep/2017:10:04:11.791] game nodes/s23 1/1/424425 34577 cD 4130/4130/4130/154/0 0/0
[27/Sep/2017:10:09:59.272] game nodes/s34 1/0/77777 3387 cD 4129/4129/4129/165/0 0/0
[27/Sep/2017:09:55:18.557] game nodes/s13 1/0/958654 84303 cD 4128/4128/4128/173/0 0/0
[27/Sep/2017:10:09:34.121] game nodes/s15 1/0/103309 3573 cD 4127/4127/4127/168/0 0/0

#haproxy config
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-218:/var/log$ cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
global
    daemon
    maxconn 200000
    log 127.0.0.1 local0

defaults
    maxconn 200000
    timeout connect 5000  
    timeout client  60000  
    timeout server 60000 

listen game
    bind *:12135
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global
    balance roundrobin
    default_backend nodes


backend nodes
    server s11 172.31.20.23:12137
    ....
```

Comment: Not sure how to "answer" this, but non-zero Send-Q would mean HAProxy has already written the data to the sockets -- it's "done."  The issue should be external to the server.